# cordovaPush.register class not found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating a small scale push notification on android. Everything seems fine but when I launch my code I get register class not found. This is the method I am getting the error

```
// Register
    $scope.register = function () {
        var config = null;

        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            config = {
                "senderID": "857533061648" 


            };
        }
        else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            config = {
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true",
                "alert": "true"
            }
        }

        $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function (result) {
            console.log("Register success " + result);

            $cordovaToast.showShortCenter('Registered for push notifications');
            $scope.registerDisabled=true;
            // ** NOTE: Android regid result comes back in the pushNotificationReceived, only iOS returned here
            if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
                $scope.regId = result;
                storeDeviceToken("android");
            }
        }, function (err) {
            ***console.log("Register error " + err)***
        }
                );
    }
```

I need help.

Comment: Did you install and include the [ngCordova plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/)?

Comment: Yes I did via the command prompt!

Comment: @JnG: Did it work ? It worked initially for me when plugin was added by downloading pushplugin from GIT to local and then added by local link. But when I tried adding plugin using direct source from GIT I am seeing this error!